# Threading an external script within a Flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask, python-multithreading

I have a Flask app that is using external scripts to perform certain actions. In one of the scripts, I am using `threading` to run the threads.

I am using the following code for the actual threading:

```
for a_device in get_devices:
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=DMCA.do_connect, args=(self, a_device, cmd))
    my_thread.start()

main_thread = threading.currentThread()
for some_thread in threading.enumerate():
    if some_thread != main_thread:
        some_thread.join()
```

However, when this script gets ran (from a form), the process will hang and I will get a continuous loading cycle on the webpage.

Is there another way to use multithreading within the app?

Comment: How intensive are the scripts? Assuming the `.join` logic is correct (I'm not sure that it is yet), if the threads are all busy for a long time, main will be blocked. Does main need to wait for the result before it can respond to a request? Why isn't the front end asynchronous to at least prevent the client from hanging until the response is ready? More details seem necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to have `subprocess` fork off a child python interpreter? Then scheduling is decoupled. If the child has startup cost that should be amortized, consider keeping the child around after initial request finishes.

Comment: @ggorlen The script using the threads connects to several wireless lan controllers and sends commands to them depending on x. As a standalone script, it takes roughly 17 seconds to complete, whereas with it integrated within Flask, takes the same amount of time without threads as it does with threads. Does Flask "hold" the threads until all have completed so they can be rendered with a "results" page?

Comment: CPython is single threaded, so the primary reason to use multithreading is when you have tasks that block on I/O. If the tasks are CPU-bound, use multiprocessing as J_H said. But at the end of the day, if you have a really intensive task (and even if you don't), there's never any reason to force the front end to freeze. Again... more details are necessary about the entire stack, but basically, if the front end is freezing, that's a JS problem, not a Python one, even if you get Flask to respond instantly, there could still be connectivity issues which you don't want to freeze the client.

Comment: When you ask "Does Flask "hold" the threads until all have completed so they can be rendered with a "results" page?" it sounds like you're serving the HTML from Flask. I would serve some HTML first, then make an ajax request to the back end to do this expensive operation. This async request will go do its thing and the client can go about their business with a friendly message/spinner and not freeze until the response arrives waiting for a page load. Once you fix that problem, you can go about optimizing your Python script.

Comment: @ggorlen I appreciate all the information. My knowledge on multithreading/multiprocessing is very minimal so thank you for going in depth. However, my issue is not the webpage load properly (I know it _can_ load properly when single-threaded), I believe it is the threading _in_ the external script.
A very brief overview of the stack: Render HTML page with form, retrieve data from HTML, call external script by importing a class _within_ the script (where the threading is taking place), render _another_ HTML page with the results from the script (as a dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implementing threading by myself in a Flask app has always ended in some kind of disaster for me. You might want to use a distributed task queue such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). Even though it might be tempting to spin off threads by yourself to get it finished faster, you will start to face all kinds of problems along the way and just end up wasting a lot of time (IMHO).

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed
>   message passing.  It is focused on real-time operation, but supports
>   scheduling as well.
>
> The execution units, called tasks, are executed concurrently on a
>   single or more worker servers using multiprocessing, Eventlet,    or
>   gevent. Tasks can execute asynchronously (in the background) or
>   synchronously (wait until ready).

Here are some good resources that you can use to get started

- [Using Celery With Flask - Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask)
- [Celery Background Tasks - Flask Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a background task, separate from the flask application the below sample approach will be helpful.

```
import threading
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def background_task():
    print("Background thread started")

# start on background
background_task_thread = threading.Thread(target=background_task)
background_task_thread.start()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "welcome";

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```